# C++ Template Parameter Function

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, linker-errors, undefined-reference

A C++ beginner here! :-)
I was trying to write a function by mimicking those in STL algorithm.

```
template<class InputIterator>
InputIterator findNegativeMax(InputIterator, InputIterator);
```

The above is the declaration in `some.hpp` file. And below is the definition of the function `findNegativeMax()`.

```
template<class InputIterator>
InputIterator findNegativeMax(InputIterator first, InputIterator last){
    Iterator position = nullptr;
    while(first <= last){
         /*some logic*/
    }
    return position;
}
```

As stated earlier I tried to mimic the STL code like 
[max_element implementation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max_element/).
but when I compile the test code which looks like

```
int main(){
std::vector<int> vec = {1,2,3,44,4,-5,-5,-2};
auto it = algo::findNegativeMax(vec.begin(),vec.end());
std::cout<<"position::"<<*it<<std::endl;
return 0;
```

}

.But when compiling with all necessary objects and attributes included I'm getting the following error

/tmp/ccma7n9Q.o: In function `main':
testAlgo.cpp:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to`__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > > algo::findNegativeMax<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator > >)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Please pardon if the question is in anyway misformed.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: declaration is in header, where did you put the definition?

Comment: also note that `Iterator position = nullptr; while(first <= last)` isnt very generic. Actually i am not aware of any iterator that would be fine with this apart from pointers. Algorithms usually return the `end` that you passed when no element can be found

Comment: ...and `first != last` is the generic way to compare iterators

Comment: the definition is in some.cpp file

Comment: and the main in test.cpp